# Display multiple images html

Tags: html, image

I'm writing a website with Flask which intended to render pictures (url's of them) received from backend via JSON. I want to render each picture with a bootstrap card component or something similar, like a carousel.

The number of pictures differs from time to time, so I can not create a precise number of cards with many div blocks - the number should be parametrized.

```
def render():
    # some code here to receive and parse json
    # images - is an array of url's
    n = len(images)
    return render_template('index.html', n=n, images=images)
```

then in .html file I want to plot n blocks, each one looking like

```
    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
      <img src="{{ images[0] | safe }}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Name</h5>
        <p class="card-text">Description</p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

How is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that just a simple for loop works

```
    {% for image in images %}
        <div class="card-body" style="width: 18rem;">
          <img src="{{ image | safe }}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
```